# WPF: Is there a performance and/or memory benefit to setting properties versus using Styles?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

Without having time to fully test this myself, I am hoping someone else may already know if there is any performance and/or memory benefit to defining a control's appearance using the control's properties versus a style (or vice versa).

Option #1:

```
<Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="20">
    ...
</Border>
```

Option #2:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20"/>
</Style>

<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
    ...
</Border>
```

Please note that I am not asking about reusability as I understand those benefits.  I am specifically wondering about "one off" styles that are specific to a given control and not reused.

Another example would be the case where I have a second Border with a margin.  Would it be more performant and require less memory to have that Border use the same style as above and directly set the Margin property or should I create a second Style resource based on the first with the new setter?

Comment: Looking at the list of precedence setting values [(link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), we find out that the `Local value` is the first (3rd place) than `Style setters` (8rd place). Therefore, by setting the values locally, these values will be set a little bit faster, than the values of other sources.

Comment: I think better terminology would be to say they are set "sooner" not "faster".

Comment: The precedence list doesn't make any statement about *when* property values are actually set. It just lists the order of precedence, that's all.

Comment: Keep in mind that I can't mark comments as answers...

Answer (score 0):

I knew that the list of precedence in on it, but not as many as I wrote in a commentary. Here's what the note says about this list of precedence in `Matthew MacDonald book [Chapter 4. Dependency Property]`:

[image]

So, when you setting the values locally, the memory is allocated for the value. When you setting these values in `Style`, and other controls that `Style` is used, the memory is allocated only once, by storing the values of `Style`.

I think, if the controls are not a lot of (the concept of fuzzy, can be 1, 2 or 3), the speed is practically no difference, but if the control is set, in this case, the difference in speed and memory storage will be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Style syntax for a collection of properties you use in only one place, you gain no memory efficiency, but you do get code readability; your main XAML code will be a little less cluttered. I've never perceived an execution speed difference between using resource dictionary styles and locally defined dependency properties.

To your second question, again, no perceptible speed difference, but you can override any resource dictionary property by specifying a local property. There is a very small amount of memory efficiency involved in using styles that way.